# How to add two output classification layers in keras?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have a neural network whose job is to classify 10 classes. Further, I want these 10 classes to be classified into 2 classes (positive -> 3 , negative -> 7). How can I achieve this in keras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to solve two different, but closely related problems. I recommend that you train your first model to predict 10 classes, and then you create a copy of the first model (including weights) except with a different output layer to support binary classification. At this point you can either:

1. Train only your final dense layer and new output layer, or
2. Train the entire model with a low learning rate

For more information you can read about [Transfer Learning](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/).

Example code:

```
model.save('model_1') # load this to retrieve your original model
model.pop() # pop output activation layer and associated params
model.pop() # pop final dense layer
model.add(Dense(1), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid')
for layer in model.layers[:-2]:
    layer.trainable = False
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

If you want to retrain the whole model then you can omit the loop setting all but the last two layers to untrainable, and choose an optimizer such as SGD with a low learning rate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you tell how to create copy of the model and how to use it as the input for the second model

Comment: I will try and update this with some code by the end of today

Comment: OK, I have added some (untested!) code. Hope that helps.